# Replace Text and Output to a new sequential file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, sequence, bigdata

I am working with a large database, so I split all of the data into manageable sizes.  To process this many files, I only think of writing a script that runs the file and replace the data filename in the file. I have searched for ways to write this script, but was of no avail.  So I went with the next idea.  This is the code that I can think of.  Many sources on open/close file and replacing text, but none of I can find will do it sequentially.  My system runs Python 2.7.

```
#!/user/bin/env python

import shutil

for i in range(5):

with open('filename{}.py', "r".format(i)) as f:
newText=f.read().replace('text{}'.format(i))

with open('filename{}.py', "w".format(i)) as f:
f.write('text{}'.format(i))


shutil.copy2('filename', 'filename{}.py'.format(i))
```

Comment: Explain your question a bit more, please: what text are you trying to replace with what? The `replace` function takes two arguments.

Comment: I was thinking it might work as a loop, open the original file then replace the data file name with the next sequential data file, then output as a new file.

Comment: So you open file1.txt, in that file you search for something, and replace that thing with file2.txt? What is the text that you are trying to replace? Or do you mean you want to open file.txt, look for all lines that have "file1.txt" in them, and copy those lines over to a new file called file1.txt?

Comment: I want to open a file.py in that file find file1.txt and replace it with file2.txt.  Then copy itself was file01.py